# Using fscanf() in c to read multiple lines

Tags: c, io

So I am trying to figure out how to use fscanf to read multiple lines from an in file. The in file looks like this:

```
8
1 8
1 7
1 9
1 8 
3 2
3 8
0 0
1 5
2 4
0 0
```

The first number I want to obtain is going to be the size of an array I will be creating so I will just set it to n(in this example that number being the 8 at the beginning).
The following digits will be as follows: the left most number will tell me what index in my array I will queue the right most number in a list I have created.
The zeros just indicate where I will be terminating.
The way I was attempting to do it thus far is:

```
fscanf(in, "%d", &n)
//have obtained n
arr[n];
while( fgets(line, MAX_LEN, in) != NULL){
 fscanf(in, "%d %d", &x, &y);
 //from here I place them in their corresponding arrays
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! This website is not a code writing service. Please post what you've tried so far and any specific questions you have, and we can assist.

Comment: Hi! Ok I've just updated it, I guess what I'm mostly unclear of is how fscanf() works on reading various lines, will it continue on the 2nd line after I have read in the first line? And keep on going until my while loop is terminated?

Comment: Did you read the documentation of [fscanf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fscanf.3.html)? You should test its result!

Answer (score 0):

Code:

```
int main()
{
    int i,  j, k;

    scanf ("%d\n", &i);
        printf  ("%d\n", i);

    while (i){
    --i;
    scanf ("%d %d\n", &j, &k);
        printf  ("%d %d\n", j, k);

    }
}
```

Execution:

```
./a.out  <input.txt
```

This is using file redirection. Also check about `freopen`. If u use this, you no need to worry about `fscanf` syntax. If you suppose to fscanf only, then there are lots of example in Google. Please refer it.

Comment: Note that the `"\n"` in `scanf ("%d\n", &i);`  attempts to read more than the usual following `'\n'`.    It attempts to read all following white-space and `scanf()` will not return until a non-white-space is detected or `EOF`.

Answer (score 0):

1) Using `fgets()` right after `fscanf(in, "%d", &n)` leaves the first line's `'\n'` in `stdin` and only read a short line.  Suggest avoid mixing `fgets()` with `fscanf()`.

2) After using `fgets()` to read the line (good idea), use `sscanf()` (or `strtol()`) to read the numbers, not `fscanf()`

```
if (fgets(line, MAX_LEN, in) == NULL) Hanlde_EOF();
if (sscanf(line, "%d", &n) != 1) Handle_BadInput();
arr[n];
while(fgets(line, MAX_LEN, in) != NULL){
  if (sscanf(in, "%d %d", &x, &y) != 2) Handle_BadData();
  ...
}
```